# Code for finding repeated entries with different data

Tags: beginner, r, data-mining

`project` is the data frame. For the purpose of the code, `HOUSE.NO` is a column of the type *character*, and `NO..OF.FAMILY.MEMBER` is another column of the type *integer*. My aim was to find out the house numbers which repeated, and then find out if the no of family members reported for each of the house matched, and identify the sets for which it didn't.

```
x<-1
matr<-NULL
matr2<-NULL
matr3<-NULL
r<-NULL
index<-NULL
repeat{


  y<-project$HOUSE.NO[-x]==project$HOUSE.NO[x]
  if (any(y)){
    r<-which(grepl(project$HOUSE.NO[x],project$HOUSE.NO))
    if(length(r)==2){
    check<-project$NO..OF.FAMILY.MEMBER[r[1]]!=project$NO..OF.FAMILY.MEMBER[r[2]]
    if(check){matr<-c(matr,r)}
    }
    if (length(r)==3){
      check2<-length(levels(factor(project$NO..OF.FAMILY.MEMBER[c(r[1],r[2],r[3])])))>1
      if(check2){matr2<-c(matr2,r)}
    }
    if (length(r)==4){
      check3<-length(levels(factor(project$NO..OF.FAMILY.MEMBER[c(r[1],r[2],r[3],r[4])])))>1
      if(check3){
      matr3<-c(matr3,r)}}
    if (length(r)>4&project$HOUSE.NO[x]!=""){index<-c(index,r)
    }
  }
  x<-x+1
  if(x>392){
    m1<-matrix(matr, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)
    m2<-matrix(matr2, ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)
    m3<-matrix(matr3, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
    break
  }
}
```

The extra argument while computing `index` is to avoid a false entry when the `HOUSE.NO` is `""`, which is true in my data frame for 3 entries. There are 393 entries, hence the final caveat before `break`.

The concerns are:

1. I am an absolute beginner in R, and the functions used here are almost all I know.
2. This code only finds if in the case of the same number repeated more than twice, only if the entire set has the same family members. I couldn't find the row indices of only the cases which mismatched. Currently, the output includes the entire set.
3. Do let me know tips on how to make this simpler. As it stands, I found this code to be quite a bit complicated.

(let me know if more details specific to the data frame/variables I am working with are needed. Or if the question is not suited to the site)

ADDENDUM

```
 HOUSE.NO NO..OF.FAMILY.MEMBER
1    14/274                    6
2    14/259                    6
3    14/217                    5
4    14/258                    4
5    14/306                    5
6    14/300                    8
7     14/96                    4
8    14/166                    4
9     14/69                    5
10    14/68                    2
```

And the expected output is just the row numbers/house.no. which fulfill the aforementioned criteria. Currently, the matrix outputs are as below. The same set is repeated in the matrix again (twice in m1, thrice in m2..etc).

```
 m1
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   20  380
 [2,]   36   68
 [3,]   37  340
 [4,]   64  191
 [5,]   36   68
 [6,]   72  329
 [7,]   88  218
 [8,]  103  199
 [9,]  111  278
[10,]  125  214
[11,]  135  387
[12,]  149  196
[13,]   64  191
[14,]  149  196
[15,]  103  199
[16,]  125  214
[17,]  215  320
[18,]   88  218
[19,]  248  317
[20,]  111  278
[21,]  310  350
[22,]  248  317
[23,]  319  324
[24,]  215  320
[25,]  319  324
[26,]   72  329
[27,]   37  340
[28,]  310  350
[29,]   20  380
[30,]  135  387
> m2
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]   43  258  354
 [2,]   65  219  269
 [3,]  169  322  323
 [4,]   65  219  269
 [5,]   43  258  354
 [6,]   65  219  269
 [7,]  169  322  323
 [8,]  169  322  323
 [9,]   43  258  354
> m3
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    2   84  211  347
 [2,]    2   84  211  347
 [3,]   99  100  101  363
 [4,]   99  100  101  363
 [5,]   99  100  101  363
 [6,]  180  185  260  263
 [7,]  180  185  260  263
 [8,]    2   84  211  347
 [9,]  180  185  260  263
[10,]  180  185  260  263
[11,]    2   84  211  347
[12,]   99  100  101  363
```

Comment: can you give a sample data section together with the expected output?

Comment: @ZahiroMor Do you want a dput of the concerned variables? I don't think it is relevant. All I want the code to do was to carry out the following objective: Find out the house.no that repeated but with different no. of.family.memebers.

Comment: yes... please dput... it'll be faster than english communication :)

Comment: @ZahiroMor Added.

Answer (score 1):

Your code uses several constructs that have a bit of smell in R.

Foremost is how you write the loop. An immediate replacement would be to replace the repeat with a `for(i in seq_len(nrow(project)))` (especially the hard coded 394 reeks)

Also you don't need to initialize the variables you will not use outside the loop - that will just prevent them from getting cleaned up after the loop.

A more R like way would be to use some higher level verbs that operate on the whole table. Such as provided by dplyr. Supposing you have something like an id in the lines you would write something like

```
left_join(project, project, on=c('HOUSE.NO')) %>% filter(id.1<id.2)
```

such commands are usually easier to read and usually much faster than looping.